# jekyll-seo-tag: Include front matter "tags" property

Tags: html, jekyll, meta-tags

I'm using [jekyll-seo-tag](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag) to automatically create meta-tags for my Jekyll blog posts.

Each post on my blog has a `tags` property in its front matter, which are used in its search system:

```
---
tags: [how, to, do, this, that, those]
---
```

I want these tags to be included in the meta-tags of the generated HTML, through jekyll-seo-tag.

How can that be done?

Comment: `<meta tags="how, to, do, this, that, those">` isn't a thing. Are you trying to output these as keywords (`<meta name="keywords" content="how, to, do, this, that, those">`)? Based on the an [old Github Issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag/issues/9), I don't think the plugin allows that by default.

Comment: Thank you, that solves my issue.